# Spring MVC Validation: Set specific error message for each validation check

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc, annotations, bean-validation

I am using JSR-303 in Spring to validate a password field. I would like to put all my validation logic in one class and display the message for each error accordingly. Is this possible? Is it a better practice to create a separate class for each validation check (i.e. PasswordLengthValidator, PasswordRegexValidator)?

Currently, I am able to display only 1 error message based on the Password interface.

Here is my interface for the @Password annotation:

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = PasswordValidator.class)
@Target( { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Password {

    String message() default "{Password}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

Here is my validator class:

```
public class PasswordValidator implements ConstraintValidator<Password, String> {

    public void initialize(Password arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public boolean isValid(String field, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
        // TODO validation validation validation
        if(StringUtils.isEmpty(field)) {
            // Message: password can not be empty
            return false;
        }

        // match some password regex
        if(field.matches("^(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=.*[!@#$&*])(?=.*[0-9].*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z].*[a-z].*[a-z]).{8}$")) {
            // Message: password should be bla bla
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your validator can send validation messages with the [`ConstraintValidatorContext`](https://javaee-spec.java.net/nonav/javadocs/javax/validation/ConstraintValidatorContext.html) API:

```
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( "this detail is wrong" )
         .addConstraintViolation();

// [..]

context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( "that detail is wrong" )
         .addPropertyNode( "street" )
         .addConstraintViolation();
```